# Maximizing $T=\frac{\sqrt{5ab+4}+\sqrt{5bc+4}+\sqrt{5ca+4}}{\sqrt{a+b+c+abc}}$ when $ab+bc+ca=3.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, maxima-minima

A friend of mine communicated me to ask a problem. I tried to prove and saw that it is not simple.

> Let $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=3.$ Find maximum$$T=\frac{\sqrt{5ab+4}+\sqrt{5bc+4}+\sqrt{5ca+4}}{\sqrt{a+b+c+abc}}.$$

My prediction: $T $ achieve maximal value $\dfrac{9}{2}$ when $a=b=c=1.$

I do with symmetric inequalities before and equality almost happens at all equal variables.

If it is not cases for this problem, I'd like to know the reason. I would very much appreciate comments and additional examples.

I checked $a=b=\sqrt{3};c=0.$ The value $\dfrac{9}{2}$ is the best, I think.

Thus, we need to prove$$\sqrt{5ab+4}+\sqrt{5bc+4}+\sqrt{5ca+4}\le \frac{9}{2}\sqrt{a+b+c+abc}. \tag{1}$$
I can easily prove $$\sqrt{5ab+4}+\sqrt{5bc+4}+\sqrt{5ca+4}\le 3\sqrt{3(a+b+c)}.$$
By using CBS inequality $$\sqrt{5ab+4}+\sqrt{5bc+4}+\sqrt{5ca+4}\le \sqrt{3}\sqrt{12+5(ab+bc+ca)}=9\le 3\sqrt{3(a+b+c)}.$$
But when I use CBS for $(1)$
$$\sqrt{5ab+4}+\sqrt{5bc+4}+\sqrt{5ca+4}\le 9\le \frac{9}{2}\sqrt{a+b+c+abc}$$where the last one is equivalent to $a+b+c+abc\ge 4.$ It is trivially wrong at $a=b=\sqrt{3};c=0.$

Thus, how can I prove it in correct way? Hope you help me out. Thank you.

Comment: An additional example of not reaching the minimum at $x=y=z$ is [the Iran 96 inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/959688)

Comment: Are you related to this question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4818515/finding-minimum-sqrta2b1-sqrtb2c1-sqrtc2a1#comment10254473_4818515.

Comment: Check your prediction by constructing a contour plot of $a$ and $b$ given that $c=\frac{3-a b}{a+b}$.

Comment: @JimB It was a different one. I didn't check it.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Thank you. In this case, I think $a=b=c=1$ is the equality case.

Comment: Given the close temporal alignment, it would seem plausible that you could be the same OP or both in the same class.